# Void lambda function

Tags: d

Is it possible to express the following function as a [lambda](https://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#lambdas) expression?

```
void f()
{
    return;
}
```

It is meant to be used as an alias in a template.

Comment: The simplest thing I could find is `void function()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(){}` should work. It uses the old-style lambda syntax, without the arrow. `() => {}` should also work, but there seems to be some kinda bug that prevents assignment from it to a `void function()` variable. Works great for template alias parameters, though.

Comment: () => {} is not a bug, in this example it need to be rewrite to () => {}()

Comment: `void function() f = ()=>{};` failing with `cannot return non-void from void function` is a bug.

Comment: Looking more into it, you are, in fact, right. `()=>{}` is the same as `(){ return (){}; }`. In other words, `{}` is an empty function in this context. I guess I've been programming too much in other languages lately, where `()=>{}` is the way to write an empty `void function()`.

Comment: I have asked in the dlang forum. There the differences are explained: https://forum.dlang.org/post/culbcxhuzhfgxftzping@forum.dlang.org